# prevent anchor tag action while dragging elements

Tags: jquery, events, touch

I am using jQuery roundabout plugin for touch Device. each element in the carousel is linked to some html page `(a href="about.html")` and i have drag and drop enables, during dragging how to disable the click event on anchor tag and revoke again when drag and drop finish.

Comment: To avoid navigation write as follows in anchor tag, <a href="about.html" onclick="return false;" >

Comment: thanks for quick reply actually link should go to about.html but just want to deactivate whiling dragging carousel to right or left.

Comment: can u post some code to suggest further?

Comment: Code look like this, each element is link to some file
and i am using this plugin http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/
when i start dragging any element it's working but when drop event or mouseUp event file it's goes to respective link (about.html)
<li class="wrapper">
    <a href="about.html" draggable="true">
    <span class="icon">About</span>
     </a>
</li>
<li class="wrapper">
    <a href="test.html" draggable="true">
    <span class="icon">About</span>
     </a>
</li>

Comment: Prevent the event on drop area. see this http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

Comment: i have done half part through <a href="about.html" onclick="return false;" > this but now how to trigger it again bcoz it disable the default behavior.

Comment: what you want to trigger? you mean href navigation?

Comment: yes when i finish drag and drop i want want to trigger default behavioral again

Comment: Have u gone through the link which i provided? To work normal navigation, remove onclick="return false;" from the anchor tag. And post some code to give more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified example showed in w3school as most suitable to your requirement. Go through following code,

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the Google link into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<a id="drag1" href="http://www.google.com" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Drag Google link into the box, then click it to navigation. I hope this will help you.